# What ONLINE to use to learn the basics of AI and Machine learning

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning

I am interested in learning the basics on machine learning and am wondering what the best **ONLINE** resources are. Keep in mind i am a total novice and know very little about the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check the Peter Norvig's web site.
http://norvig.com/

However, texts such as those of Russel and Norvig or Alpaydin would keep you better focused.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks there was some good stuff there :)

Answer (score 5):

The [lecture series at Stanford](http://see.stanford.edu/see/courseinfo.aspx?coll=348ca38a-3a6d-4052-937d-cb017338d7b1) on machine learning is really good. I would recommend that you start there.

There are also some good books that are available online:

- [The Elements of Statistical Learning](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/)
- [Information Theory, Inference and Learning Algorithms](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/itila/)

Answer (score 1):

[See my answer to a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006793/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-started-in-artificial-intelligence-programming/4006851#4006851). In short, if you are looking for practitioner's knowledge, such as when and how to apply things like Neural Networks and Bayesian filtering, there are links to several useful books there. Understanding the theory requires math, the link has several book recommendations to direct toward what and how, and you should be prepared to spend some time reading research papers.